# How to infer prisma types from multiple projects?

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have a project that is structured as follows

```
dashboard
 -- prisma-project-1
 -- prisma-project-2
 -- client-of-prisma-project-1-and-prisma-project-2
```

It is a dashboard meant to combine data from two databases and represent them in some way.
I then proceed to import the clients of `prisma-project-1` and `prisma-project-2` in `client-of-prisma-project-1-and-prisma-project-2`.

However, when I import prisma clients in `prisma-project-1` in `client-of-prisma-project-1-and-prisma-project-2`, the prisma types are those from `prisma-project-2`.

How do I import prisma clients in `prisma-project-1` and `prisma-project-2` in `client-of-prisma-project-1-and-prisma-project-2`without their types overriding each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly specify locations where `PrismaClient` and `Types` of each prisma project should be generated.

Setting the location in a custom [output](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/generating-prisma-client#using-a-custom-output-path) path should resolve this.

Example:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "../src/generated/client"
}
```

Import statement would look like:

```
import { PrismaClient } from './generated/client'
```